# Eth_call through oraclize

Tags: json-rpc, oracles, infura, external-api

so I have a contract deployed on Ropsten and now I'm trying to access the public variable using a JSON RPC call through Infura and Oraclize.

Here's my contract:
contract test_contract { 
    uint public last_a;

```
function double(uint a) public returns(uint) { 
  last_a = a;
  return 2*a;   
 }

 function getLastA() public constant returns(uint){
     return last_a;
 }

 function getMethod() public constant returns(bytes4){
     return bytes4(keccak256("getLastA())"));
 }
}
```

Ok. So I get the method getLastA using the getMethod,  pad it to 32, get the contract address on Ropsten...and now this is my call:

```
url post - json(https://ropsten.infura.io/).result
 params -  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":3,"method":"eth_call","params":[{"to":"0x76a83b371ab7232706eac16edf2b726f3a2dbe82","data":"4b9a1598000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"], "latest"}
```

You can see my oraclize query [here](http://app.oraclize.it/home/test_query#VVJMKFBPU1Qp:anNvbihodHRwczovL3JvcHN0ZW4uaW5mdXJhLmlvLykucmVzdWx0:IHsianNvbnJwYyI6IjIuMCIsImlkIjozLCJtZXRob2QiOiJldGhfY2FsbCIsInBhcmFtcyI6W3sidG8iOiIweDc2YTgzYjM3MWFiNzIzMjcwNmVhYzE2ZWRmMmI3MjZmM2EyZGJlODIiLCJkYXRhIjoiNGI5YTE1OTgwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAiXSwgImxhdGVzdCJ9)

Just wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if this is even possible.  The value it should return is 17 if anyone else thinks they have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few things wrong with your HTTP request:

1. The JSON was malformed due to a missing curly brace and a mis-placed square bracket.
2. The `data` field had the wrong function selector in it.
3. The `data` field was missing the leading `0x`.
4. The `data` field was the wrong length. Although there's no need to pad with zeros, you *can* do that as long as you get the length right. You had an odd number of digits (71).

Here's a valid JSON payload:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_call",
    "params": [
        {
            "data": "0xad3b80a8",
            "to": "0x76a83b371ab7232706eac16edf2b726f3a2dbe82"
        },
        "latest"
    ]
}
```

`POST`ing this to `https://ropsten.infura.io` yields a `result` of `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011` (17 in decimal).

Here's a working Oraclize query: http://app.oraclize.it/home/test_query#VVJMKFBPU1Qp:anNvbihodHRwczovL3JvcHN0ZW4uaW5mdXJhLmlvLykucmVzdWx0:IHsianNvbnJwYyI6IjIuMCIsImlkIjozLCJtZXRob2QiOiJldGhfY2FsbCIsInBhcmFtcyI6W3sidG8iOiIweDc2YTgzYjM3MWFiNzIzMjcwNmVhYzE2ZWRmMmI3MjZmM2EyZGJlODIiLCJkYXRhIjoiMHhhZDNiODBhOCJ9LCAibGF0ZXN0Il19.

Out of curiosity, what's the reason for using Oraclize rather than just calling the contract directly? Are you doing cross-chain communication between contracts?

Comment: wow...you rock man.  And good job with the guess.  Just playing around with using oraclize to bridge two chains

Comment: And just curious, does my 'getMethod' not get me the proper function selector?

Comment: Just spotted the issue. You have an extra parenthesis in the string you're hashing. By the way, I think you can just do `return this.getLastA.selector`.

Comment: Figures..and that is a much easier way.  Thanks for the help!